how persist swapoff -a
for kubernetes reuirements, I disable swap with the following:
sudo swapoff -a
sudo sed -i '/ swap / s/^\(.*\)$/#\1/g' /etc/fstab

but after reboot, swapoff get on again. I nee to reissue swapoff -a to be able to continue.
How can this be persisited?
Thanks in advance

Always check what the commands you enter should achieve, and check afterwards whether they succeeded. You have changed one or more lines in /etc/fstab. What do they look like now? Please edit your question and add the line(s) to it.

You should check that swap is not re-enabled during boot, first disable the swap entries with comment out in /etc/fstab
You can try to reboot to see if it work, if not check the active swap unit with sudo systemctl list-units --type swap then disable them with something like sudo systemctl mask your_swap
then reboot to see if that worked

Thanks yes, I commented the line for swap in the fstab and di fix the issue, thanks again
